# Connection problems to RDS Postgres instance

Tags: database, postgresql, post, amazon-rds, psql

Trying to connect to my AWS RDS Postgres DB and having some problems..

- Created an initial DB in RDS configuration when created the DB instance and named it test_db

ERROR IM GETTING :

```
psql postgres://Username:Password@Host(RDS instance endpoint):Port/test_db
psql: error: FATAL:  database <user> does not exist
```

THNAKS !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what i was looking for ( used postgres as DB name instead what i tried previously

```
psql postgres://Username:Password@Host(RDS instance endpoint):Port/postgres
```